# Create function to categorize BMI in multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r, function, categories

This is my first post here and I'm newer to R so I apologize if this post is worded weird.

I am working on an analysis of a large dataset for a single year. I want to categorize continuous BMI data into the categories ranging from "underweight" to "obese". To categorize across multiple years of this dataset I want to write a function that would be able to be used over multiple years where the datasets are named slightly different.

Is there a way I can write this function so I can apply it to different years of the dataset without rewriting my code??

```
bmi_categories<- function(df_bmi_cat){(as.factor(ifelse(df$BMI2< 18.5 &df$AGE2>6, "Underweight",(ifelse (18.5<=df$BMI2 & df$BMI2<25 & df$AGE2>6, "Normal Weight",(ifelse (25<=df$BMI2 & df$BMI2<30 & df$AGE2>6, "Overweight",(ifelse (30<=df$BMI2 & df$AGE2>6, "Obese","")))))))))}
```

The first 6 observations of the dataframe look like this:

```
    AGE2    BMI2
1   15  22.50087
2   17  24.88647
3   14  22.70773
4   9   23.49076
5   7   22.14871
6   16  23.10811
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who responds!

Comment: It would be helpful to have a sample of the data you're using, even just a few rows to help understand the structure.

Comment: Sure thing! I am going to try and put the first 6 observations here. 
 AGE2 BMI2
1 15 22.50087
2 17 24.88647
3 14 22.70773
4 9 23.49076
5 7 22.14871
6 16 23.10811
So if the above data comes from year 1 of the large dataset, I'd like to be able to apply the function to year 2, year 3, etc.  without having to rewrite all my code. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the names of the columns are different each time, I would provide the function not with the entire dataframe, but with the specific data columns.

##### example data

```
df1 <- data.frame(AGE1 = c(6, 12, 24, 56, 32), BMI1 = c(20, 18, 27, 31, 29))

> df1
  AGE1 BMI1
1    6   20
2   12   18
3   24   27
4   56   31
5   32   29
```

##### function

```
bmi_categories <- function(bmi, age) {
  category = factor(rep(NA,length(bmi)), levels = c("Underweight","Normal Weight","Overweight","Obese")) # NA as default value, you could set "" as default, but then you should also add "" to the vector of levels
  
  category[bmi<18.5 & age>6] <- "Underweight"
  category[18.5<=bmi & bmi<25 & age>6] <- "Normal Weight"
  category[25<=bmi & bmi<30 & age>6] <- "Overweight"
  category[30<=bmi & age>6] <- "Obese"

  return(category)
}
```

*(You could also use the code by JaredS and turn that into a function. I personally try to avoid using external libraries where possible, so the code is easier to run on another computer.)*

##### call the function and assign return value to new column

```
df1$class <- bmi_categories(df1$BMI1, df1$AGE1)

> df1
  AGE1 BMI1       class
1    6   20        <NA>
2   12   18 Underweight
3   24   27  Overweight
4   56   31       Obese
5   32   29  Overweight
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want but with a lot less nested functions.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(Classification = case_when(AGE2 <= 6 ~ "",
                                         BMI2 < 18.5 ~ "Underwwight",
                                         BMI2 < 25 ~ "Normal weight",
                                         BMI2 < 30 ~ "Overwwight",
                                         BMI2 >= 30 ~ "Obese"
                                         ))
```

This will create an additional column for the weight classification.

```
A tibble:6 x 3
AGE2   BMI2   Classification
<dbl>  <dbl>  <chr>

15  22.50087    Normal weight       
17  24.88647    Normal weight       
14  22.70773    Normal weight       
9   23.49076    Normal weight       
5   22.14871            
16  23.10811    Normal weight       
6 rows
```

This is also very easy to apply as a function if required.